# Convert text data into percentage in C#

Tags: c#

I am getting data into a text field and I need to display it as a percentage. Is there a function to perform this?

Ex: in my column I have `"0.5", "0.1","0.2","0.25"` etc., which needs to be displayed as 
`50%,10%,20%,25%` etc., What is the best way to do it?

Comment: In WPF you could use a Converter. Please provide more information. Winforms or WPF? What objects are in your view etc etc

Comment: With WPF, you can also specify the format directly in a binding

Comment: check this also : http://pranayamr.blogspot.ca/2012/06/format-number-to-display.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should do this in two phases:

- Parse the text as a *number* so you've got the value as your "real" type. (As a general rule, parse from text as early as you can, and format to a string as late as you can... operations between the two will be a lot simpler using the natural type.)
- Format the number as a percentage using the [standard numeric format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) for [percentage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#PFormatString)

So:

```
decimal percentage = decimal.Parse(input);
string output = percentage.ToString("p0");
```

Notes:

- You should consider both input and output culture; are you always expecting to use "." as the decimal separator, for example?
- Use `decimal` rather than `double` to exactly represent the value in the text (for example, the text could have "0.1" but `double` can't hold a value of exactly 0.1)
- You can add things like desired precision to the formatting; see the linked docs for details; the example gives just an integer percentage, for example

Comment: "p" tends to have extra decimals on the end (`0.2` will become `20.00%` IIRC) - "p0" may be preferable

Comment: @MarcGravell: I've added notes around this :) Will edit to use p0 in the example though.

Comment: a typically thorough answer, +1 for being culturally sensitive.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest would be to parse it (must be a double) then convert it back to a string, formatting it as a percentage.

```
var percentageString = double.Parse(doubleString).ToString("p1");
```

Now, *some of you* hoity-toity types may say that [decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the correct type to use in this case.

Well, yes, if you need an additional *12-13 digits of precision*.

However, most of us *real folk* (and I'm all about keeping it real) are fine with [double's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx) 15-16 digits of precision.

The real choice is whether or not your code is using doubles or decimals in the first place.  If you are using doubles in your code, just stick with doubles.  If decimals, stick to decimals.  What you definitely *do* want to avoid is having to convert between the two any more than is absolutely necessary, as there be dragons.  And unexpected runtime bugs that can corrupt your data.  But mostly dragons.

Comment: Double's a bad idea IMO - the input data is *naturally* decimal, so why use double?

Comment: @JonSkeet: Look, you, stop being all smart and stuff.